# How do bigrams in R handle 1 word inputs?

Tags: r, nlp

I am doing some NLP work on a data set of survey responses (using tidy). I am seeing some odd results when I get my bigram and trigram counts—the results include bigrams and trigrams that are not present in the data set.

Bigram examples incldue:

- "yes yes"
- "no no"
- "yes no"

Trigram examples include:

- "yes yes yes"
- "no yes yes"
- "x no no"

Here is my code:

```
# bigram counts
bigrams <- survey %>%
unnest_tokens(ngram, token = "ngrams", n = 2,
              input = survey_response)

# trigram counts
trigrams <- survey %>%
unnest_tokens(ngram, token = "ngrams", n = 3,
              input = survey_response)
```

I do not believe that this is a code issue, because I have selected bigrams & trigrams in this manner before and not had this issue.

I'm wondering if one-word responses in the `survey_response` input are causing the issue. There are many answers that are only "yes" or "no." How does R handle the construction of bigrams or trigrams when an input observation is only one word? Will it duplicate the word in some way, or cause other issues?